# Disable the use of aaplication/json in one request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i write this code for send request to upload file :

```
 const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', "https://localhost:44372/api/v1/Upload/UploadNewsPic"
  , formData, { reportProgress: true });
  this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
      this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response)
      this.messsage = event.body.toString();
  })
```

and i use the interceptor to add auto `application/json` to header but i no need to add this header for this request .

**how can i do this??????????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to interceptor, you can check for url and avoid adding this header for this particular request:

```
@Injectable()
export class AddHttpHeaderService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const url = request.url;

    if (url === 'https://localhost:44372/api/v1/Upload/UploadNewsPic') {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    // other part of interceptor related to adding application/json to header
    ...
```